# get_home_url() just returns current URL

Tags: wordpress, url, wordpress-theming

My problem is simple, I need a "home" link for my WP template, and the function `get_home_url()` is simply returning the current url. So if I'm on `"example.com/?cat=2"`, that's the url I get for my home button .

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I'm pulling my hair out.

Comment: do you use an `echo` before it?

Comment: You're right, this was exactly the problem. *facepalm*

Comment: And to think, after all the time I spent trying to convince Rasmus to add a <?= ?> tag back in the PHP 2/3 days when I did that for a living...

Comment: Please include the *full, exact* code you tried, for clarity. Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's just home_url(). So:

```
echo home_url();
```

Will output the homepage of your Wordpress installation.

Comment: `get_home_url()` also works, just remember to add an echo before it or use the shorthand <?= ... ?> PHP tags.

Comment: echo is not required before `home_url()`

Comment: @DrDeo Incorrect. [Feel free to review the source code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.8/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L2916) and notice that `home_url` is a *return* function. Therefore, an echo - or a shorthand PHP echo `<?= ... ?>` - is required.

Comment: To clarify for all: home_url() is an alias and just calls get_home_url() … So both functions are exactly the same an do a return … echo is therefor needed.

Comment: @GDY Since this answer has gained a bit of traction, it should be noted that `home_url` and `get_home_url` are *not* exactly the same. When using them without any arguments, then they are virtually identical. However, `get_home_url` takes a Blog ID as its first argument (for multisite purposes) which can trip people up if they're expecting to pass in a `$path` value, which `home_url` accepts as its first argument.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried:

```
echo get_bloginfo('url')
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to echo that function, so it should be:

```
<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>
```